# Question about conguence module m: If $n> 0$ and $n$ is not a multiple of $3$, prove that $a = 3^{2n} + 3^n + 1$ is divisible by $13.$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I would like to solve this problem using the idea of congruence module m, but I have no idea how to start. Could someone help me?

If  $n> 0$  and $n$ is not a multiple of $3$, prove that $a = 3^{2n} + 3^n + 1$ is divisible by $13$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: $3^3\equiv1\bmod13$

Comment: $(a-1)(a^2+a+1) = ?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$3^3=27=2\times13+1\equiv1\bmod13$, so $3^{3n}\equiv 1 \bmod 13$,

so $3^{3n}-1=(3^n-1)(3^{2n}+3^n+1)\equiv 0\bmod13$,

which means $3^n-1\equiv0\bmod13$ or $3^{2n}+3^n+1\equiv0\bmod13$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: It has now become much clearer how to resolve this question.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to think in such a situation is to make a table of the data, working modulo $13$, i.e. in the ring $R=\Bbb Z/13$. The table is:
$$
\begin{array}{|r|c|l|}
\hline
n & 3^n\in R & 3^{2n}+3^n+1\in R\\\hline
0 & 1 & 1+1+1 = 3\\
1 & 3 & 9+3+1 = 13=0\\
2 & 9 & 3+9+1 = 13=0\\\hline
3 & 1 & 1+1+1 = 3\\
4 & 3 & 9+3+1 = 13=0\\
5 & 9 & 3+9+1 = 13=0\\\hline
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\end{array}
$$
and it repeats itself. The main point is to see that the powers of $3\in R$ repeat with period three, and then check these three cases.

Comment: could prove by induction:  base cases $3^2+3+1$ and $3^4+3^2+1$ are divisible by $13$, and $3^{2(n+3)}+3^{n+3}+1=729\cdot3^{2n}+27\cdot3^n+1\equiv3^{2n}+3^n+1\bmod13$

Comment: This is already too complicated, "induction for us" is not "induction for an exam". Here it is enough to compute the powers $3^0$, $3^1$, $3^2$, $3^3$, so we have here periodicitiy for the only piece that counts, $3^n$, so the first three cases are enough, and now we have simple computations, no logic, no other issues that are easy but annoying to type to care of... @J-W-Tanner (and it takes a lot of time to find this (at))

Comment: @J.W.Tanner which is not working, so a new try is needed...

Comment: ... and this one seems to be also not working, anyways...